# Bugs - Program that Creates a Directory in C

Tags: c, error-handling, linux

I have the following code that creates a directory in C. I tested it multiple times, reviewed it a few times and it looks fine at the moment.

What I really wanna know is what bugs does it have and how can I fix them ? (comparing it with the `mkdir` command from linux)

```
#include "ourhdr.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <dirent.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("./i78 /locatie/nume_director sau ./i78 nume_director\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char buff[PATH_MAX];
    strcpy(buff,argv[1]);

    if (mkdir(buff,S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)<0)
    {   
    printf("%s: cannot create directory '%s': File exists\n",argv[0],buff);
    }
    else

    printf("\n Creare director [%s]\n",buff);


}
```

Comment: Please state explicitly, in the question, whether or not [the code presented works as intended, to the best of your knowledge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (`looks fine [from my perspective]` doesn't *quite* cut it in my book.)

Comment: @greybeard happy ?  that was the last problem of the post

Comment: Fine with me. To be entirely explicit, you could use *Potential bugs in unanticipated cases* (a wording from the on-topic page).

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential buffer overflow - the length of `argv[1]` may be up to [`ARG_MAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499490/10396), which is likely larger than `PATH_MAX`.

The "File Exists" message may be misleading, [`mkdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html#ERRORS) can also fail because of permissions, out of space, invalid characters in the name, ...

It's good practice to put `{` `}` around all conditionals, including the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

- `strcpy(buff,argv[1]);` is unnecessary. You may work directly with `argv[1]`.
- The error message is misleading. There are plenty of reasons for `mkdir` to fail, other than "File exists". Use `perror`.
- Do not `#include` files you don't need, in this case `<limits.h>` and `"ourhdr.h". BTW, what _is_`"ourhdr.h"`?
- Do not mix languages. The error message is in English, the rest are in Portugese. In the production-grade code, one would use `i18n`.